# How to access component function in a component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have different jsx files.I want to access Menu.jsx component function in Header.jsx function to open menu. I am using Material-UI also. So Here I have a function "handleToggle" in Menu.jsx and I want to trigger this function from a button "onLeftIconButtonTouchTap" which is available in Header.jsx. How can I access component internal function from any other component, should I need to maintain any hierarchy?

App.jsx

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <main>
                <Menu/>
                <Header/>
                <Body/>
                <Footer/>
            </main>
        )
    }
}
```

Header.jsx

```
export default class Header extends BaseMUI{
    render(){
        return (
            <header>
                <AppBar
                    title="title"
                    onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
                    iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
                />
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

Menu.jsx

```
export default class Menu extends BaseMUI{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false
        };
    }

    handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

    handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.refs);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <nav>
                <RaisedButton
                label="Open Drawer"
                onTouchTap={this.handleToggle}/>

                <Drawer
                    docked={false}
                    width={200}
                    open={this.state.open}
                    ref="drawer"
                    onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}>
                        <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
                </Drawer>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create parent component, store there state of opening menu, and change props of the menu - here an example, how it can be implemented in only react, without Flux and Redux, will be more right to use them, if you have many idential situations.

```
class MenuContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = { 
        isMenuOpen = false
     } 
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(newProps, newState) {
     return newState.isMenuOpen != this.state.isMenuOpen 
  }

  openMenu = (isMenuOpen ) => {
      this.setState({isMenuOpen : isMenuOpen });
  }

  render () {
    return (
       <Header : isMenuOpen={this.state.isMenuOpen}
          openMenu= {this.openMenu}/>
       <Menu isMenuOpen={this.state.isMenuOpen})
    }
}
```

And then in your menu component

```
shouldComponentUpdate(newProps) {
   return this.props.isMenuOpen != newProps.isMenuOpen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you Header.jxs and Menu.jsx are in same hierarchy, you can solve in 2 ways...

1) you can fire a event from Header.jxs and listen for the action in Menu.jsx

2) Using react-redux way, fire the action on click and observer the props changes  in Menu.jsx

Comment: Not using redux